# Events are not displayed in Day view of Tapku Calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, tapku

Events are displayed in such case.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];   
    self.data = @[@[@"Hamburger Bliss", @"Wendys", @15, @0, @18, @0], @[@"Fishy Fishy Fishfelayyyyyyyy", @"McDonalds", @5, @30, @6, @0]];  
}
```

But if hours are greater than @500

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.data = @[@[@"Meeting with five random dudes", @"Five Guys", @960, @0, @1000, @30],@[@"Unlimited bread rolls got me sprung", @"Olive Garden", @500, @0, @510, @0]];
}
```

Events are not displayed.

I want to know the reason why events are not shown and how to show the events.

Is there another way to add events?

Comment: Issue has been reported there: https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/issues/235 but no sign of correction.

Comment: i have seen it already. But no use